# The program says "setVisible(false)" is not a function, why is this problem?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Im making a program in Phaser in JavaScript and im using the statement `questions.setVisible(false)` in my program, but this appears - `Uncaught TypeError: question.setVisible is not a function`, which clearly is. The statement is in the `create` function, it doesn't work in the other functions either.
Code:

```
var Game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, 'phaser-example', {create})

var question;

function create() {
    question = Game.add.text(Game.width/2, Game.height/2, 'On which day is Pi celebrated?', {align: 'center'}).anchor.setTo(0.5);
    question.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: "_which clearly is_" What makes you say that? I'm not familiar with Phaser, but according to the docs, [`.setTo()`](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Point.html#setTo) returns a [`Phaser.Point`](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Point.html). I don't see anything about a `.setVisible()` method in that class.

Comment: which version of phaser, are you using?  _(doesn't seem like phaser 3)_

Comment: how to check what version im using?

Comment: @BobTheBean In the ***browser console*** there is a banner showing the version.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use **phaser 3**, not phaser 2/CE/... or so. Since the most documentations and informations are for phaser 3. **That said,** it seems to me, that *your problem* is two fold:

1. you cannot chain the all the properties/methods like this, as the comments mention it returns a different object. You would have to do this:

   ```
   // like this `question` is a Text object
   question = game.add.text(game.width/2,game.height/2, 'On which day is Pi celebrated?', {align: 'center', stroke:'white', fill:'white'});

   // set the anchor of the `question`
   question.anchor.setTo(0.5);
   ```
2. the function `setVisible` doesn't exist for the text class. (atleast it is not mentioned in [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser-ce/Phaser.Text.html#visible), **side note:** in phaser3 this function exists). For phaser 2/CE you would have to set the property `visible`:

   ```
   question.visible  = false;
   ```

So the whole function should look something like this:

```
    function create() {
        question = game.add.text(game.width/2,game.height/2, '...', {align: 'center'});
        question.anchor.setTo(0.5);
        question.visible  = false;
    }
```